# How do I preload all the movies when all the tags are unselected?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am building a small functionality for my project, basically i have an array of movie object that contains name of movies and tags assigned for that movies. I want to display the movies on the basis of tags selected, i.e if the tag “comedy” is selected , then all the movies that have “comedy” as one of their tags will be displayed

For this purpose I’m maintaining a map which consist of key as “tagname” and its “status” i.e (seleted/unselected) as value in form of state. I have written the logic for it, but my doubt is that whenever the page is loaded at first all the movies should be displayed because no tag is selected on load by default, how shall i implement it as i am initialising all the values in state(map) as false(unselected).
Please help, Here is the link for sandbox that i have implemented till now -
https://codesandbox.io/s/movie-tags-exp-4mur0?file=/src/Tags.js

Comment: This question requires a lot more information. What specifically have you already tried and why didn't work. What code is having unexpected behavior and what did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the following changes to your code,

1. Instead of maintaining the state as an object , You can maintain a list where you can add the tags and remove them

   ```
       const [selectedTags, setSelectedTags] = useState([]);
   ```
2. with #1 in place now you can add and remove the tags as below

   ```
   const manipulate = (tag) => {
       if (selectedTags.includes(tag)) {
         setSelectedTags((prevSelectedTags) =>
           prevSelectedTags.filter((existingTag) => existingTag !== tag)
         );
       } else {
         setSelectedTags((prevSelectedTags) => [...prevSelectedTags, tag]);
       }
     };
   ```
3. Updating the style for the selected tag will be changed as

   ```
    backgroundColor: selectedTags.includes(tagname) ? "green" : "white"
   ```
4. You can remove the `check` as your filtered data is the derived state based on the selected Tags. Now you can filter as

   ```
    const filteredData =
       selectedTags.length > 0
         ? data.filter((movie) =>
             movie.tags.some((tag) => selectedTags.includes(tag))
           )
         : data;
   ```
5. Once filtered you can use the `filteredData` to render your movies list

   ```
   {filteredData.map((movie, index) => {
           return (
             <div key={index}>
               <h3>{movie.name}</h3>
               <p>{movie.desc}</p>
               <br />
             </div>
           );
         })}
   ```

**Working Sandbox**

[Filter Movies Based on Tags](https://codesandbox.io/s/movie-tags-exp-forked-1nmbv?file=/src/Tags.js)